# jQuery create selector with element, variable and element

Tags: jquery, html, foreach, jquery-selectors

I'm using the multiple rss feed script as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260717/loop-through-multiple-rss-sources-and-outputting-in-different-divs/). It works as intented, but instead of outputting items into divs, I would like to use unordered lists and list items, like this:

```
<div id="content_1">
   <ul></ul>
</div>
<div id="content_2">
   <ul></ul>
</div>
```

I have changed the script to write divs, but I have a problem with the selector inside the "each" statement: `$("#content_"+ Content).append('<li></li>')...`

I would like my selector to look like this: `$("#content_1 > ul).append('<li></li>')...`

I have tried with `$("#content_"+ Content).find("ul").append('<li></li>')` but then the script doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried `$("#content_"+ Content + " > ul").append('<li></li>')` ?

Comment: What is `Content`???

Comment: @aytee77: It doesn't work. The script doesn't output anything.
Content is a variable that counts the number of feeds and adds this number to the id used for each feed's element:
var Content = parseInt(urls.indexOf(Query)) + 1;

Comment: Whoa, my mistake. In the code there was this line: 
$("#content_" + Content).html('');
Removing it made  aytee77's suggestion work.

Comment: @aytee77 Please allow me to accept your input as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `$("#content_"+ Content + " > ul").append('<li></li>')` ?